# Does Qt 6 only support a few common text encodings?

Tags: c++, qt, character-encoding, qt6

Qt 6 introduced the [`QStringConverter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringconverter.html) class as a replacement for the Qt 5 [`QTextCodec`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html) class. `QTextCodec` is deprecated in Qt 6 and only available as part of the [`core5compat`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore5compat-module.html) compatibility module. `QTextCodec` will probably be removed in Qt 7.

Now, `QTextCodec` supported a whole lot of different text encodings (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#details)), but `QStringConverter` only supports the most common Unicode text encodings and ISO-8859-1 (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringconverter.html#details)). However, legacy text encodings like e.g. [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) are still needed today to decode text files from the pre-Unicode era.

So, how can I continue to use any of these text encodings in Qt 6? Is the Qt 5 compatibility module really the only way?

Comment: They want you to use ICU/iconv/winapi etc directly.

Comment: See [QTBUG-86437](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86437), [QTBUG-117362](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-117362) and so on :(.